# Drilling into a Coldfusion Struct

Tags: coldfusion, cfml

I have this ColdFusion struct that I dumped:

[image: CFDUMP output]

I'm trying to drill into this farther to get the `DTCREATED` variable.

This was generated from the following query:

```
gotResults = queryService.execute(sql="SELECT * FROM someTBL WHERE  EXPORTID in 
(#whereVariable#)" );
```

Can anyone tell me how to drill further into this ColdFusion struct?

Comment: Which version of ColdFusion are you using?

Comment: nothing wrong with this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `gotResults.getResult().DTCREATED`.

`gotResults.getResult()` returns a [Query object](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-tags/tags-p-q/cfquery.html), so just use `.DTCREATED` (case-insensitive) to get to the column. It will return the value in the first row of that column by default.